# If I concatenate two hex numbers, is the result guaranteed to be hex?

Tags: postgresql, hex, md5

I am wanting to hash two fields, then convert the result into an integer.
This is in a database view so the faster the better.

My current approach below is to get this single hash value and then pass that into a hex_to_int() function.

```
 md5(
  md5(field_one::text) || 
  md5(field_two::text)
  )
```

But ideally I could just pass this to the hex_to_int function. The result always appears to be a hex number but I can't guarantee it. Is the concatenation of two hex numbers always a hex number?

```
  md5(field_one::text) || 
  md5(field_two::text)
```

Background if relevant: I need an ID column that is a unique positive integer (not bigint). As it's for a db view it needs to be calculated rather than incremental. I have field_one and field_two that together are always unique, but of course concatenating them is out of the question because (1, 35) and (13, 5) would be appear the same. I know there are chances of collisions with my current approach, but for my purposes this is an acceptable risk. I'm just looking for the quickest way to hash two integers into a single integer.

Comment: Yes, the concatenation of two positive integer hexadecimal numbers is always a hexadecimal number. That is the same as for decimal numbers (and number to any other base).

Comment: Can you explain why you need a unique ID on a view? And is there a specific reason why you want to hash two values (or even one) to get the id?

Comment: It needs to be a unique, unchanging id for a third party tool that is designed to work with tables not views hence the unchanging id requirement. But really I'd just like to know the answer for general knowledge outside of my task.